# How to plot data from different blocks with lines in Gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a data file with blocks of x/y values. Each block contains 16 lines with x/y pairs and each block represents those positions in a different time. http://pastebin.com/0teRrfRU

I want to plot the trajectory of a specific particle. To do that, I've written `plot 'pos.dat' u 2:3 every ::n:0:n:i`, where `n` is the n-th particle and `i` is the time up to which I want the trajectory plotted (I can then loop over the i to generate an animation).

This runs fine, but when I add `w lines` nothing gets plotted, and I don't understand why. Is there a way to plot this with lines? The only alternative I see is writing a script to parse the data file and generate a new one with only the values I want (effectively acting as `every`), but I don't want to do that if I can do it in Gnuplot.

Comment: In case this still might be of interest, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53246690/7295599

Answer (score 1):

After a closer look to your data, your case has some speciality.
Like in [Plotting same line number of several blocks data with gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53223558/7295599) you can plot the file into a table via `with table` which will remove the empty lines and hence lines will be connected.

However, some of your particles disappear on one side and re-appear on the opposite side. If you plot this `with lines` you will get a line through the whole graph which is certainly undesired. You can workaround this if you introduce a function `Break()` which returns `NaN` if the difference of two successive x- or y-values are larger than 90% (to be on the safe side) of the x- or y-range , respectively. The effect of `NaN` is that the line will interrupted.

**Code:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0 version at the time of OP's question)

```
### plotting trajectories
reset session

set term gif animate delay 3 size 400,400
set output "SO30744875.gif"
set size square

FILE = 'SO30744875.dat'

set key noautotitle
stats FILE u (N=column(-1),M=column(1),$2):3 nooutput
xrange = STATS_max_x-STATS_min_x
yrange = STATS_max_y-STATS_min_y

set table $Data
    plot FILE u 1:2:3 w table
unset table

Break(col1,col2) = (x0=x1,x1=column(col1), y0=y1,y1=column(col2), \
                   abs(x1-x0)<0.9*xrange && abs(y1-y0)<0.9*yrange ? column(col2) : NaN)

do for [i=0:N] {
    plot for [j=1:16] x1=y1=NaN $Data u 2:(Break(2,3))every M::j-1::(i+1)*M w l, \
                      FILE u 2:3   every :::i::i w p pt 7, \
                      FILE u 2:3:1 every :::i::i w labels offset 0.7,0.7
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]