# Plotting same line number of several blocks data with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with the following structure

```
block1: line 1
        line 2
        line 3
       .....
block2: line 1
        line 2
        line 3
        ......
block3: .....
```

To plot only the block2, I use the command

```
plot 'file' u x1:x2 every :::2::2 w l
```

How to gather only line 1 of each block on the `plot` command?

Comment: Just as extra hint. When I am using the command `plot 'file' u x1:x2 every ::3::3 w p` I am getting an output. it plots line 3 of every block on a single plot? But If I change the option `w p` to `w l` nothing appears. Looks like the issue was also reported on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744875/how-to-plot-data-from-different-blocks-with-lines-in-gnuplot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Revised versions)*

If you have empty lines in your data, gnuplot will separate the plotted line. So, if you are selecting just the first line of each block you could plot this `with points` and `with linespoints`, but when plotted `with lines` you won't see anything because all lines are disconnected.

Three possible solutions:

1. plot the selected data into a table (datablock) and plot this datablock. (Simpler plot command but probably more memory usage).
2. plot your data `with vectors` from one datapoint to the next. (No extra memory (datablock) required, but more complex plot command).  This looks like `with lines`. If you want `with linespoints` you need to plot the same data a second time `with points`.
3. you could filter your data and remove empty lines with an external tool and plot the filtered data. However, if possible, I prefer gnuplot-only solutions because they are platform-independent.

**Data:** `SO53223558.dat`

```
# block line  x    y
 0      0     1    0
 0      1     2    1
 0      2     3    2
 0      3     4    3

 1      0     5   10
 1      1     6   11
 1      2     7   12
 1      3     8   13

 2      0     9   20
 2      1    10   21
 2      2    11   22
 2      3    12   23
```

**Script 1:** (requires gnuplot>=5.0.0, because of datablocks)

```
### plot values of different blocks connected with lines
reset session

FILE = "SO53223558.dat"

set table $Data
   plot FILE u 3:4 every ::0::0 w table
unset table

set key top left

plot FILE  u 3:4 w lp pt 7 lc "grey" ti "all data",\
     $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "green" lw 2 ti "1st of each block"
### end of script
```

**Result 1:**

[image]

**Script 2:** (requires gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### plot values of different blocks connected with lines
reset

FILE = "SO53223558.dat"
set key top left

plot FILE  u 3:4 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "grey" ti "all data",\
    x1=y1=NaN FILE u (x0=x1,x1=$3):(y0=y1,y1=$4):(x0-x1):(y0-y1) every ::0::0 \
       w vec lc rgb "blue" lw 2 nohead ti "1st of each block"
### end of script
```

**Result 2:**

[image]

**Addition:**

If you want to do this with several files, try the following example below.
The datafiles should be named `SO53223558_n.dat` where `n` is from 1 to 3. No data and output is shown here.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### plot every Nth line of all blocks of several systematic files
reset session

count = 3   # number of files
N = 0       # Nth line of each block, index is zero based

set table $Data
    do for [i=1:count] { 
        FILE = sprintf("SO53223558_%d.dat", i)
        plot FILE u 3:4 every ::N::N w table
    }
unset table

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red"
### end of script
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still some incomprehensions. Can you explain these two instructions `0:3:4` and `::0::0`?

Comment: As it was not already complicated, I am also, I am looping through many files of the same kinds. I am using text file for `set table "name_i.dat"`, where I generate `name_i.dat` into a `do for` loop using `sprintf("name_%d", i)`. Is there a way to do the same with something that looks like `$DATAi` (ref. your code)? .

Comment: I didn't know how your data exactly looks like, so I assumed something.
0 is a "pseudocolumn", in gnuplot check `help pseudcolumns`.
::0::0 is the first dataline of each block, check `help every`.
The "trick" is to plot the desired data into a new table (i.e. datablock). In my test data example `plot $Data u 3:4 every ::0::0 with table` and later `plot $Data2 u 1:2 w lp` would also work.

Comment: if you wan to do this with several files... see addition in my answer.